# OO Design: inheritance vs type (enum) variable

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, enums

Is there a general best practice when to use inheritance:

```
public class Information {
  private String text;
}

public class Message extends Information {
}

public class Faq extends Information {
}

public class News extends Information {
}
```

and when to use enum as a member variable to distinguish:

```
public enum InformationType {
  MESSAGE, FAQ, NEWS
}

public class Information {
  private String text;
  private InformationType type;
}
```

In the code that I work with I have the second - a type field and what bothers me is the code

```
public void displayInformation(final Information information) {
  if (information.getType == InformationType.MESSAGE) {
     ....
  } else if (information.getType == InformationType.FAQ) {
     ....
  } else if (information.getType == InformationType.NEWS) {
     ....
  } else {
     // some error handling
  }
}
```

This is definitely a code smell and I don't see how you can have the enum as member variable and not have these if-elses!? If that is true, then you should never have enums as types for the objects, but I see this "pattern" so often!

Comment: I hope my blog helps https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2015/12/03/enums-as-type-discriminator-anti-pattern/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Different tools for different jobs.

**1. Use an enum class to declare a set of fixed constants known at compile time.**

Good examples of things that are conveniently and cleanly described by enum classes are: suits and ranks from a deck of playing cards, and planets in the solar system.  Both example have in common the fact that the objects are constant (or reasonably constant; there is no law against evolving an enum class) and can all be instantiated at the start of the execution of your program.

Enum classes are otherwise very similar to ordinary Java classes.  You can add constant-specific data to each constant by defining instance fields and a constructor in the enum class, and you can define constant-specific behavior by writing constant-specific methods.

It is easy to write rich enum types in Java and they can be quite powerful.  Used correctly, they will make your code more streamlined and easier to maintain.  Enum classes are often the best choice WHEN you are dealing with a fixed set of constant objects.

Enums with constant-specific methods often make your program code much easier to read and robust to maintain.  For example, instead of:

```
public void displayInformation(final Information information) {
    if (information.getType == InformationType.MESSAGE) {
        ....
    } else if (information.getType == InformationType.FAQ) {
        ....
    } else if (information.getType == InformationType.NEWS) {
        ....
    } else {
        // some error handling
}
```

You could define an abstract method in the enum class `InformationType` called, for example, `displayInfo()` and then write constant-specific methods like this:

```
public enum InformationType {
    MESSAGE {
        @Override 
        public String displayInfo() {
            ....
        }
    },
    FAQ {
        @Override 
        public String displayInfo() {
            ....
        }
    },
    :
    :
    LAST_TYPE {
        @Override
        public String displayInfo() {
            ....
        }
    };

    abstract public String displayInfo();
}
```

Using constant-specific methods in this way in rich enum types is a very good alternative to using switch-case blocks in your code which can become quite ugly very quickly.  Once you have implemented this rich enum type, you could replace your original method with the much, much cleaner and easier to read:

```
public void displayInformation(final Information information) {
    information.getType().displayInfo();
}
```

**2. Use a subclass when you wish to use an arbitrary number of objects that have an "is a" relationship with a superclass.**

A subclass is an ordinary Java class that extends a superclass.  The right time to use a hierarchy like this is when the instances of your class all have an "is a" relationship with a superclass.  The prototype example would be superclass `Bicycle` and subclass `MountainBike`.  All mountain bikes are bicycles.

If there is no well-defined "is a" relationship between the subclass and superclass, you are likely much better off not using inheritance at all (favor composition instead of inheritance).

**3. Avoid the trap of using enum constants to describe a hierarchy.**

For example, you have a class `Shape` with an instance field that holds an enum constant of type `ShapeType` (and you write the enum class to have constants CIRCLE, RECTANGLE, TRIANGE).

When such *Tagged Classes* are simple, sometimes using an instance field as a tag is the right thing to do, but avoid the pitfall of using tags as a thinly veiled disguise for a class hierachy.  It could certainly be true that the best and cleanest way to represent `Shape` is as an abstract superclass with subclasses `Circle`, `Rectangle`, and `Triangle` (all of these -are- shapes).

Comment: Like mentioned in another comment the strategy pattern can be a good alternative to rich enums if they happen to have more responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

"Strategy pattern" usually solves problems like this.

"Strategies eliminate conditional statements. The Strategy pattern offers an alternative to conditional statements for selecting desired behavior. When different behaviors are lumped into one class, it's hard to avoid using conditional statements to select the right behavior. Encapsulating the behavior in separate Strategy classes eliminates these conditional statements." http://java.boot.by/scea5-guide/ch07s03.html

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately most of the challenge in programming is about getting each concept and decision in exactly one place, to minimize cost of change in the project.

In this case then, if there is only one place that you have a different behavior based on the InformationType, then it is fine to have the list of if/elses, since it is no more code than making several different subclasses (in fact, it is slightly less code).

However, if you need this differentiation in multiple places in your code, then it is better to abstract that into InformationType specific code blocks (like having subclasses implement a common interface), since otherwise you are duplicating code.

Answer (score -1):

Enums are the right way to do it, in my opinion.

Instead of multiple if-else lines, you would use a Map.  This separates presentation from data:

```
private final Map<InformationType, String> infoFormats;

{
    Map<InformationType, String> map = new EnumMap<>(InformationType.class);
    map.put(InformationType.MESSAGE, "Message: %s");
    map.put(InformationType.FAQ,     "FAQ item: %s");
    map.put(InformationType.NEWS,    "News: %s");

    assert map.keySet().containsAll(EnumSet.allOf(InformationType.class)) :
        "Programmer error:  Not all InformationType values accounted for!";

    infoFormats = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}

// ...

public void displayInformation(final Information information) {
    String format = infoFormats.get(information.getType());
    String rawText = information.getText();
    String text = String.format(format, rawText);
    show(text);
}
```

If the differences in display text are more substantial than just a format, the Map can be a Map of functions:

```
private final Map<InformationType, UnaryOperator<String>> infoFormats;

{
    Map<InformationType, String> map = new EnumMap<>(InformationType.class);
    map.put(InformationType.MESSAGE, s -> String.format("Message (%,d chars): %s", s.length(), s));
    map.put(InformationType.FAQ,     s -> "FAQ item: " + s);
    map.put(InformationType.NEWS,    s -> String.format("%tF %<tT - %s", Instant.now(), s));

    assert map.keySet().containsAll(EnumSet.allOf(InformationType.class)) :
        "Programmer error:  Not all InformationType values accounted for!";

    infoFormats = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}

// ...

public void displayInformation(final Information information) {
    String rawText = information.getText();
    String text = infoFormats.get(information.getType()).apply(rawText);
    show(text);
}
```

You can allow for even more customizability with `Map<InformationType, Function<Information, String>>`, if that’s necessary.

Comment: Same can be done with a `Map<Class<? extends Information>, UnaryOperator<String>>`

Comment: @k5_ You could, but then you’d be using inheritance where it’s not necessary.  Always prefer composition over inheritance.